# How to Convert Any Language String into UTF-8 Unicode in SSRS Report?

Tags: unicode, reporting-services, utf-8, ssrs-2012

I Have an issue showing in  SSRS report a string  that contains 
Japanese letters and Roman Numerals:

"貴社特別値引Ⅲ"

(the last char is III (3) in Roman )

When previewing the report I'm getting this string:

[image: Can see the Japanese BUT not the Roman numeral]

Any Thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: What character set is that report using? If some Japanese encoding, that may not be able to capture all of Unicode correctly. Or it could "just" be a font problem.

Comment: The Character Set include Japanese and English as well as Latin Numerals 1,2,3...

Comment: I mean, what is the character set called ? UTF-8? SJIS? EUC-JP? Try using UTF-8.

Comment: I've Changed the Character Set from ASCII to UTF-8, Still not working..https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182005(v=sql.100).aspx